# align dropdownlist in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, alignment

I'm trying to right-align a dropdownlist similar to my textfields.
It works in firefox and IE, but I can't figure it out why it wont align properly in chrome.

**HTML**

```
<div id="metaDataEditInner">
    <label>Document name</label>
    <input class="field"></input>
    <label>Document description</label>
    <input class="field"></input>
    <label>Document remarks</label>
    <input class="field"></input>
    <label>Document type</label>
    <select class="dropdownfield">
    </select>
    <br />
    <div style="clear:both">
        <button id="test" class="defaultButton">Save metadata
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#metaDataEditInner
{
    margin: .5em 5px;
    text-align: right;
    width: 550px;
}

#metaDataEditInner label
{
    float: left;
    line-height: 1em;
    margin-top: 3px;
}

#metaDataEditInner .field
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 350px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1em;
    padding: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#metaDataEditInner .dropdownfield
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 360px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1em;
    padding: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color:Black;
}
```

Any idea's ?

I've made a fiddle to illustrate the problem

http://jsfiddle.net/ZE5ss/2/

Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the `<br />` after the `</select>`. Works for me on chrome, see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6b98f/11/).

Answer (score 1):

I didn't want a say but if i saw you markup it's totally wrong.

1) Always put **form** element inside `<form>`.

2) **input** & **button** is an self closing element. Write like this:

```
<input class="field" />
 <button id="test" class="defaultButton" value="Save metadata" />
```

3) **select** is not work without `option` Tag. Write like this:

```
<select class="dropdownfield">
   <option></option>
</select>
```

Comment: thx for the tips, but it's not solving my issue :)
Btw knockout.js is not handling the self closing elements very well, thats why I used this markup.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code its working fine in all the browsers:

```
<div id="metaDataEditInner">
<table>
<tr>
<td>
    <label>Document name</label>
        </td>
        <td>
    <input class="field"></input>
    <tr>
<td>
    <label>Document description</label>
        </td>
        <td>
    <input class="field"></input>.
    <tr>
<td>
    <label>Document remarks</label>
        </td>
        <td>
    <input class="field"></input>
    <tr>
<td>
    <label>Document type</label>
        </td>
        <td>
    <select class="dropdownfield">
    </select>
    <tr>
<td>    </td>
        <td>
        <button id="test" class="defaultButton">Save metadata

        </button>

    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: I'd rather not use a table for this.. :p